# orderBy not filtering numbers correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ng-repeat` directive.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="list in vm.customer.lists | orderBy: list.id track by $index">
    <td>[[list.name]]</td>
    <td>[[list.locations.length]] Location<span data-ng-cloak data-ng-if="list.locations.length !== 1">s</span></td>
    <td><a data-ng-href="/#/locations/manage/list/edit/[[vm.customer.id]]/[[list.id]]" class="button expand">Manage Locations</a></td>
</tr>
```

I'm repeating 3 lists in `vm.customer.lists`

I'm trying to accomplish least to greatest by `list.id` (1, 2, 3, etc.)

Maybe I can't orderBy `list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be,

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="list in vm.customer.lists | orderBy: 'id' ">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = 
      [{
      id: 4,
      name: 'sachin'
      
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Saurav'
     
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Dravid'
     
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Dhoni'
    
    }];
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">  
    <li ng-repeat="list in customer | orderBy: 'id' track by $index">
     {{list.name}}
    </li>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing quotes in filter

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="list in customer.lists | orderBy: 'id' track by $index">
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    'lists': [{
      id: 4,
      name: 'T',
      locations: []
    }, {
      id: 1,
      name: 'S',
      locations: []
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'R',
      locations: []
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'O',
      locations: []
    }]
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="list in customer.lists | orderBy: 'id' track by $index">
      <td>{{list.name}}</td>
      <td>{{list.locations.length}} Location<span data-ng-cloak data-ng-if="list.locations.length !== 1">s</span>
      </td>
      <td><a data-ng-href="/#/locations/manage/list/edit/[[vm.customer.id]]/[[list.id]]" class="button expand">Manage Locations</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```